# How to unpack a list in java to sublist

Tags: java, arraylist

I got a list by the following code:

```
ArrayList<String> single = new ArrayList<String>()

- [Document{{packetsLost=0,id=ssrc_1848956494_recv, timestamp=2019-07-11T07:18:42.923Z}}, Document{{packetsLost=10, timestamp=2019-07-11T07:20:43.413Z}}]
- [Document{{packetsLost=0, id=ssrc_1848956494_send, timestamp=2019-07-11T07:18:42.923Z}}, - Document{{packetsLost=10, timestamp=2019-07-11T07:20:43.413Z}}]
- [Document{{packetsLost=0,id=ssrc_929521404_recv, timestamp=2019-07-11T07:18:42.923Z}}, Document{{packetsLost=10, timestamp=2019-07-11T07:20:43.413Z}}]
- [Document{{packetsLost=0,id=ssrc_929521404_send, timestamp=2019-07-11T07:18:42.923Z}}, Document{{packetsLost=10, timestamp=2019-07-11T07:20:43.413Z}}]
```

I am new to java, how can I create sub-lists from the list retrieved, knowing that packet ​​lost values in a list and timestamp in other list  with a sign (id) like:

```
 1- id=ssrc_1848956494_recv 
    [0 , 0]
    [2019-07-11T07:18:42.923Z, 2019-07-11T07:20:43.413Z]

 2- id=ssrc_1848956494_send 
    [0 , 0]
    [2019-07-11T07:18:42.923Z, 2019-07-11T07:20:43.413Z]

 3- id=ssrc_929521404_recv 
    [0 , 0]
    [2019-07-11T07:18:42.923Z, 2019-07-11T07:20:43.413Z]

 4- id=ssrc_929521404_send 
    [0 , 0]
    [2019-07-11T07:18:42.923Z, 2019-07-11T07:20:43.413Z]
```

Comment: In addition, your expected output does not agree with the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can make use of streams here to generate the two lists:

```
List<String> packetsList = single.stream()
    .map(x -> x.replaceAll(".*packetsLost=(\\d+).*", "$1"))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

List<String> timestampsList = single.stream()
    .map(x -> x.replaceAll(".* timestamp=([^}]+).*", "$1"))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: This... seems to assume input is a list of Strings. It doesn't appear to be.

Comment: i changed my question , you can help me

Comment: I can't help you, because your new expected output can't really be represented by a string.  Your question is omitting information which we would need to help you again.